# Translate a block of code to list comprehension syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists with the next structure and a pointer:

```
 list1 = [{'ip1':[1,2], 'ip2':[2,3]}, {'ip3':[3]}, {'ip4':[4]}, {'ip1':[1,2], 'ip2':[3], 'ip3':[5,6,7]}]
 list2 = [1, 3, 4, 10, 25]
 pointer = 'ip2'
```

If a value in list2 is **not in any list** of the inner dictionaries of list1 using pointer as key, append it to a new list:

```
list3 = [1, 4, 10, 25]
```

try the next code but it doesn't produce my desired output...

```
for inner_dict in list1:
    list_3 += [e for e in list2 if e not in inner_dict[pointer]]
```

Comment: this is poor question. Although you say "it works", does it? Your example code does't look like it is valid. For instance, 'list3 += e'. e is not a list, this will be runtime error I think (you are trying to add a list and an int. use append(). Also, what if inner_dict[pointer] fails?

Comment: Thank you Tim! You are right! Edited! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existing answer from Andrej is great, but if you have a lot of data, it's building the lookup table from scratch for every element of `list2`.

Although it's less succinct, you can speed it up by building the lookup set once and filtering `list2` from there. This means you only touch each dict element a fixed number of times and complexity is a multiplication of all relevant list lengths rather than an exponent.

```
from itertools import chain

lookup = set(chain(*[d[pointer] for d in list1 if pointer in d]))
result = [x for x in list2 if x not in lookup]
```

Comment: Nice, and your solution is indeed faster according to my benchmark. But there is no need to iterate over a dictionary just to filter for `k == pointer` when you can access `d[pointer]` directly. If you do `lookup = set(chain.from_iterable([d[pointer] for d in list1 if pointer in d]))` then it's more than twice as fast as before.

Comment: Good call, not sure what I was thinking!

Comment: For the record, my timings for this solution are 1.17 microseconds vs. 4.51 microseconds for Andrej's. `chain.from_iterable(...)` is very marginally faster than `chain(*...)`.

Comment: I'm not too worried about micro-optimizing the constant time factor because it's a one-off expense, so as the data gets to be large enough it disappears. Nice to know, though.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `any()` builtin method in the list comprehension:

```
list1 = [{'ip1':[1,2], 'ip2':[2,3]}, {'ip3':[3]}, {'ip4':[4]}, {'ip1':[1,2], 'ip2':[3], 'ip3':[5,6,7]}]
list2 = [1,3,4,10,25]
pointer = 'ip2'

list3 = [i for i in list2 if not any(i in dct.get(pointer, []) for dct in list1)]
print(list3)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 4, 10, 25]
```